# Another links into website don't redirect https

Tags: traefik

With below configuration, my URL was automatically redirect to https

[image]

But content into then doesn't direct.

[image]

This is current configuration on CoreOS:

In traefik.toml

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
#      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
#      entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/ee.crt"
        keyFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/private.key"
```

In docker-compose.yml

```
...
labels:
    - traefik.enabled=true
    - traefik.backend=oms_nginx
    - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com
    - traefik.http.redirect=https
    - traefik.frontend.redirect=https
    - traefik.http.frontend.entryPoints=http
    - traefik.http.frontend.redirect=https
    - traefik.https.frontend.entryPoints=https
    - traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true
    - traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
    - traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https
    - traefik.docker.network=proxy
    - traefik.port=80
```

Answer (score 0):

```
labels:
- traefik.enabled=true
- traefik.port=80
- traefik.docker.network=proxy
- traefik.backend=oms_nginx
- traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com
- traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect=true   # <- it's a redirect only on 443 port
- traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https
- traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https  # <- It's the reditection label
- traefik.frontend.redirect=https             # <- non existing label
- traefik.http.redirect=https                 # <- non existing segment label
- traefik.http.frontend.entryPoints=http      # <- it's a segment label
- traefik.http.frontend.redirect=https        # <- it's a segment label
- traefik.https.frontend.entryPoints=https    # <- it's a segment label
```

- Segment labels must be only use for container with multiple port binding.
  https://docs.traefik.io/v1.6/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers-with-multiple-ports-segment-labels

#### A redirect by frontend

In `traefik.toml`

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/ee.crt"
        keyFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/private.key"
```

Change your labels to that:

```
...
labels:
- "traefik.enabled=true"
- "traefik.port=80"
- "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
- "traefik.backend=oms_nginx"
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com"
- "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
- "traefik.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https"
```

This suppose you have create 2 entry points named `http` and `https`.

#### A global redirect

In `traefik.toml`

```
[entryPoints]
    [entryPoints.http]
    address = ":80"
      [entryPoints.http.redirect]
      entryPoint = "https"
    [entryPoints.https]
    address = ":443"
      [entryPoints.https.tls]
        [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
        certFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/ee.crt"
        keyFile = "/etc/traefik/ssl/private.key"
```

In `docker-compose.yml`

```
...
labels:
- "traefik.enabled=true"
- "traefik.port=80"
- "traefik.docker.network=proxy"
- "traefik.backend=oms_nginx"
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:mydomain.com"
- "traefik.frontend.entryPoints=http,https"
```